# How to count probability of given numbers?

Tags: probability

I have these numbers and probabilities:

```
Activity | Probability
 A       |  2.49
 B       |  3.97
 C       |  1.27
```

The lower the probability number is, the more probably will happen the respective activity.
I am trying to figure out that probability in percentage.

If are given these numbers:

```
Activity | Probability
 A       |  2.00
 B       |  2.00
 C       |  2.00
```

Then the probability that an activity will happen is 33% (for activity A, B, and C because the `probability` in this case is the same for each `activity`).

But how to count the percentage probability in the first case?

Thank you

Comment: This does not appear to be a Mathematica question.  Consider posting it [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Total the "probabilities" (these are not), then divide each by that total...

Answer (score 1):

Probably

> P(A)=2.49/(2.49+3.97+1.27)